# How do you change view by changing dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a dropdown list in a View. And if I change the selection, I want to change immediately the values in the View. The textbox of Type and Description.
How do you do that?

```html
@Model GenreModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditGenre", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @model GenreModel
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Edit genre</h1>
        <p>&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Save" /></p>
        <p>
            <label>Select genre: </label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Description, new SelectList(ViewBag.GenreList, "Description", "Description"), new { onchange = "onChangeSelection(this.value);" });
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Type</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Type)
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Description</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Description)
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

This is the method in the Controller.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditGenre(string description)
{
    var dto = _genreService.GetGenreByName(description);
    var model = _mapper.Map<GenreDto, GenreModel>(dto);
    ViewBag.GenreList = _genreService.GetAllGenres().OrderBy(g => g.Description);
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally:

```
<script>
    function onChangeSelection(val) {
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: @Url.Action("EditGenre", "Home"),
                //type: "POST",
                data: { description: val },
                success: function (data) {
                    // put result of action into element with class "result"
                    $('.result').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert(val + ' not found.');
                }});

}
</script>
```

Comment: Select item has an event called onChange. When user changes selection in dropdown, this event fires up. You can look it up.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071994/mvc-dropdownlist-onchange-event-with-value

Comment: I got further with your url. But not yet to the solution. Thanks for thinking along.

Answer (score 1):

Change the DropDownList like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Description, new SelectList(ViewBag.GenreList, "Description", "Description"));
```

And submit the form in the onchange function:

```
<script>
    $("#Description").on("change", function () {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have to press on the submit-button. And that's not what I want. It's almost the same solution that I have found.

Comment: No, you don't need to press the submit button, it will automatically submit when the select option changed.

Comment: Then I want to know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: I tested your codes, there is one more `'{'` in your scripts before `$.ajax`, remove it, then it can work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my DropDownList didn't fire a Submit. I leave the javascript and using a hidden field.
And this solution works fine.

```
 <p>
            <label>Select genre: </label>
            @Html.Hidden("#Discription")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Description, new SelectList(ViewBag.GenreList, "Description", "Description"), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" });
        </p>
```